# Загрузить и применить изменения ветки origin/master на локальный репозиторий

Tags: git, github

Работаю над один проектом с 2-х компьютеров. На одном поработал -  тут же запушил коммиты.

Теперь прихожу ко 2-му компьютеру, как загрузить произведенные коммиты в его локальный репозиторий?

Ввел команду `git fetch` - коммиты вроде загрузились, но изменений не произошло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сначала ввел команду для перемещения head на master:

```
git checkout master
```

А git предложил ввести команду, удовлетворившую мою потребность:

```
git pull
```